# Как можно зациклить стек на си

Tags: c

Есть у меня стек такого вида:

```
typedef union {
    float f;
    int   i;
    struct{
    int16_t  lo;
    uint16_t hi;
    };
} uniondata;

typedef struct {
    int    *MCALC_TOP;
    uniondata  data[32];
    int     size;
} Mcalc;

extern Mcalc MCALC;
```

Со следующими методами:

```
void initStackMcalc(Mcalc *stack)
{
 stack->size = 0;
}


void pushMcalcF(Mcalc *stack, float value)
{
 stack->data[stack->size].f = value;
 stack->size ++;
}


float popMcalcF(Mcalc *stack)
{
 float val = 0.0;
 val = stack->data[stack->size].f;
 stack->size --;
 return(val);
}
```

Нужно его как-то зациклировать. Когда стек заполнен и вызывается метод 'pushMcalcF' нужно сдвинуть и записать последней с сохранением размера стека. Метод 'popMcalcF' должен брать с вершины стека если произошел сдвиг.

Comment: Честно не понимаю, что вы понимаете под "_зациклить стек_". "_Нужно его как-то зациклировать_" как вы себе представляете это?

Comment: думаю, человек пытается изобрести [Кольцевой буфер](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80)

Comment: в вашем `pop..` ошибка. сначала нужно отнимать размер `stack->size --;val = stack->data[stack->size].f;` Последовательность действий должны быть **обратными** к `push..`. Вопрос не понятен. Если цикл переполнен, то если размер стека не менять, то можно смело остановиться с исключением переполнения.

Comment: @zhilenkov - "Нужно его (стек) как-то зациклировать."  - Подозреваю, что имеется в виду совсем не то.  Удалять самый нижний элемент стека абсурдно по самой природе стека. Он нужен именно для того, что бы восстановить всю историю. Если это станет невозможно - то нет никакого смысла в стеке.

Я думаю, что Вы имеете в виду буфер для потоковых данных.  В таких буферах допускается отбрасывание элементов при переполнении.  Самым известным типом такого буфера является "Кольцевой буфер". См: http://www.avrki.ru/articles/content/cicle_buffer/

Comment: Кольцевой это FIFO, мне нужен LIFO.

Comment: Кольцевой буфер может быть как FIFO так и LIFO. Главное - кольцо.  FIFO циклят - потому что там неважно перетирание данных, главное что бы не переполнился стек - это гарантирует целосность данных, а LIFO при переходе через кольцо - будет самостираться и гарантировать целосность данных - невозможно, область применения циклического LIFO... ну развечто есть источник который злоупотребляет переполнением стека, и "древние" данные источнику не нужны. Поэтому не советую кольцевой-LIFO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я подумал сделать что-то типа такого. Может где ошибся. Проверьте.

```
#define McalcSize 32 // размер стека
#define McalcSizeMask (McalcSize - 1) // маска
typedef union {
    float f;
    int   i;
    struct{
    int16_t  lo;
    uint16_t hi;
    };
} uniondata;

typedef struct {
    int    *MCALC_TOP; // указатель на верхней элемент в стеке калькулятора
    uniondata  data[32];
    int     size;
} Mcalc;

extern Mcalc MCALC;
```

Методы:

```
void initStackMcalc(Mcalc *stack)
{
 for(uint8_t i = 0; i < McalcSize; i++){
     stack->data[i].i = 0;
 }
 stack->size = 0;
}


void pushMcalcF(Mcalc *stack, float value)
{
 stack->data[++stack->size].f = value;
 stack->size &= McalcSizeMask;
}


float popMcalcF(Mcalc *stack)
{
 float val = 0.0;
 if(stack->size != 0){
 val = stack->data[stack->size --].f;
 stack->size &= McalcSizeMask;
 }
 return(val);
}
```

Comment: Да, верно. Вы же вкурсе, у вас нет теста на переполнение, при переполнении такого стека (переходе через размер McalcSize) - просто будут "стёрты" данные - точнее непонятные данные пойдут, можно долго потом искать где баг. Наверно поэтому LIFO как правило не делают циклическим - смысл цикличности не понятен. FIFO - там смысл "задержка данных", и этой задержкой согласуют более быстрые обработчики данных которые переодично обрабатывают поток данных с более медленными.

Comment: Наверно главное смысл. Применять это можно 1)если программа злоупотребляет стеком, и старые данные гарантировано не нужны. 2)если добавить две "контрольные точки" и по ним делать сброс данных на диск или в память (в обе стороны) - то получится "безразмерый" стек.

Comment: Или вариант - подсунуть свинью при увольнении - потому что баг рано-ли позно проявится - а найти будет сложно.

Comment: Вот представьте - человек, у которого мало знаний, берёт вашу программу, она работает. Он говорит о чудо. Через неделю его программа - заглючит. Он не поленится и натыкает вам минусов. Потому что тут нет ни предупреждений, ни контроля переполнения данных, ни хотя бы "возвращение нулей" вместо "стёртых данных". По хорошему нужны методы canPush или canPop хотя бы,  и описание зачем это надо и как этим пользоваться. Или хотя бы unsafePush unsafePop, а push и pop обвёрнуты через canPush или canPop. Тогда будет защита от стирания.

Comment: опять та же ошибка `stack->data[++stack->size].f = value;` - будет ошибка памяти. `data[McalcSize]` -> Crash.

Comment: @AlexGlebe можете объяснить в чем проблема?

Comment: В массиве данные хранятся по индексам : `data[0]..data[McalcSize-1]`. Ваше выражение сначала увеличивает `size` на единицу и когда `size` становиться `McalcSize` и потом присваивает по новому индексу значение происходит ошибка памяти, а уже совсем позже этот индекс обнуляется. Правильный путь прибавление размера делать **после** присваивания, а не до.